# Unable to display Google Static maps encoded polyline path using URI

Tags: java, google-polyline, google-maps-static-api

I am using the given example in [Google Static Map Polyline Path](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/dev-guide#Paths) to display the encoded polyline path with fillcolor using `URIBuilder`. `URIBuilder` escapes the 'enc' part of URI as expected. Due to this the area is not outlined or filled with color. I have tried replacing `\\\\` with `\` before passing to URI and also added `@` in the end.

Below is the URL I am trying to generate using URIBuilder:

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap
>   ?size=400x400&center=40.653279,-73.959816&zoom=11
>   &path=fillcolor:0xAA000033%7Ccolor:0xFFFFFF00%7Cenc:}zswFtikbMjJzZ%7CRdPfZ}DxWvBjWpF~IvJnEvBrMvIvUpGtQpFhOQdKpz@bIx{A%7CPfYlvApz@bl@tcAdTpGpVwQtX}i@%7CGen@lCeAda@bjA%60q@v}@rfAbjA%7CEwBpbAd_@he@hDbu@uIzWcWtZoTdImTdIwu@tDaOXw_@fc@st@~VgQ%7C[uPzNtA%60LlEvHiYyLs^nPhCpG}SzCNwHpz@cEvXg@bWdG%60]lL~MdTmEnCwJ[iJhOae@nCm[%60Aq]qE_pAaNiyBuDurAuB}}Ay%60@%7CEKv_@?%7C[qGji@lAhYyH%60@Xiw@tBerAs@q]jHohAYkSmW?aNoaAbR}LnPqNtMtIbRyRuDef@eT_z@mW_Nm%7CB~j@zC~hAyUyJ_U{Z??cPvg@}s@sHsc@_z@cj@kp@YePoNyYyb@_iAyb@gBw^bOokArcA}GwJuzBre@i\tf@sZnd@oElb@hStW{]vv@??kz@~vAcj@zKa%60Atf@uQj_Aee@pU_UrcA
>   &key=YOUR_API_KEY

Please help.

Comment: you might compare your results with this library's results: https://github.com/hoereth/google-static-map-creator

Answer (score 1):

The URL request didn't work because of the unnecessary space between parameters, I've removed the spaces in your URL request, you may try the URL below:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=400x400&center=40.653279,-73.959816&zoom=11&path=fillcolor:0xAA000033%7Ccolor:0xFFFFFF00%7Cenc:}zswFtikbMjJzZ%7CRdPfZ}DxWvBjWpF~IvJnEvBrMvIvUpGtQpFhOQdKpz@bIx{A%7CPfYlvApz@bl@tcAdTpGpVwQtX}i@%7CGen@lCeAda@bjA%60q@v}@rfAbjA%7CEwBpbAd_@he@hDbu@uIzWcWtZoTdImTdIwu@tDaOXw_@fc@st@~VgQ%7C[uPzNtA%60LlEvHiYyLs^nPhCpG}SzCNwHpz@cEvXg@bWdG%60]lL~MdTmEnCwJ[iJhOae@nCm[%60Aq]qE_pAaNiyBuDurAuB}}Ay%60@%7CEKv_@?%7C[qGji@lAhYyH%60@Xiw@tBerAs@q]jHohAYkSmW?aNoaAbR}LnPqNtMtIbRyRuDef@eT_z@mW_Nm%7CB~j@zC~hAyUyJ_U{Z??cPvg@}s@sHsc@_z@cj@kp@YePoNyYyb@_iAyb@gBw^bOokArcA}GwJuzBre@i\tf@sZnd@oElb@hStW{]vv@??kz@~vAcj@zKa%60Atf@uQj_Aee@pU_UrcA&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

You may also visit the Best Practices in [Building a Valid URL](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/web-service-best-practices#BuildingURLs) to learn more about creating URL requests.